# VBA Populate array in 1 row

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm struggling with arrays and their type. I've a single Worksheet column A (type General) filled with integer numbers like "629984". When, in VBA, I declare an array and try to populate it directly based on a range selection from row `14` to `lastrow + 13` like this:

```
ReDim TempID(1 To lastrow + 13, 1 To 1) As Integer
TempID = OppsClosed.Range("A14:A" & lastrow + 13).Value
```

I get a Type Mismatch error. Putting and Ad-watch on `OppsClosed.Range("A14:A" & lastrow + 13).Value` I understand that the type is `Variant/Double`.
*Each cell in the range from `A14` trough `A13955` is filled with integer numbers like "629984" as you can see from the figure below*

[image]

**My question is**: How can I avoid using `variant`? Is the loop the only way?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say `8781341`, are they individual numbers in separate columns?

Comment: Nope, as u can see the selection is trough 1 column only `"A14:A"`

Comment: So they're in individual rows?

Comment: I clarified in the first post. Yes, each cell in the range from `A14` trough `A lastrow+13` is filled with integer numbers like `"629984"` as you can see from the figure above

Comment: AFAIK you can't avoid `Varaint` and a loop in this case.  It's one of the few cases where Variants _should_ be used.  And BTW `8781341` doesn't fit in an Interger, you would need a Long

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thanks for the answer. Since a read that best practice (for speed) is avoid Variants I was trying to avoid them.

Comment: @gmeroni yes, it's best to avoid them when you can.  In this can I don't think you can (except by a loop, but that would be counter-productive)

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yup. I'm just new to VBA so I'm learing all the best practices and the workarounds :) Thanks again

Comment: @gmeroni I'll add it as an answer so Q can be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can't avoid `Varaint` and a loop in this case. It's one of the few cases where Variants should be used.

It is best to avoid `Variant`s when you can. In this can I don't think you can (except by a loop, but that would be counter-productive)

And BTW `8781341` doesn't fit in an Interger, you would need a Long